# Magento - add link to My Account in Main Menu navigation bar

Tags: magento, categories, account

I was wondering if it possible to link a category to 'My Account'. Basically I would like to make 'My Account' more prominent, by creating a category - 'My Account' which appears in the main menu navigation bar.

Is there a way of linking this category to 'My Account'? So that when the user clicks on 'My Account' in the navigation bar it links through to through the customers account.

Any ideas?

Fiona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the preferred way of doing it. However you can edit the template to display the link in direct association with the categories.